# Creating Stacked Bar Column Chart with CODE BEHIND

Tags: c#, code-behind, stacked

I need to create a Stacked column chart as shown in the picture. 
X-Axis : Component name
Y-Axis : Number of bugs
Stacks : For each component I need to create stacked charts which tell me:
    ---> For each component category(Audio/Video) I need to say that I have x number of HIGH , MEDIUM, LOW, SHOWSTOPPER bugs.

I have the data in the format of :
Category NAME ||
  BUG TYPE : numbers
  BUG TYPE : numbers
  BUG TYPE : numbers
  BUG TYPE : numbers

Sample Data: 
AUDIO::=> 
  high: 30
  medium: 17
  low: 1
VIDEO::=>
  high: 1
PERIPHERAL::=>
  medium: 15
  high: 14
  low: 1
  showstopper: 1
SENSOR::=>
  medium: 2

These data displayed above were created with some LINQ queries. So it is not in a dictionary. The Code to create the data above:

```
var dbQuery = from bug in RawListData
              group bug by new { bug.category, bug.customer_priority } into grouped
              select new { 
                  Category = grouped.Key.category,
                  Priority = grouped.Key.customer_priority,
                  Count = grouped.Count()
              };

            var query = dbQuery.ToLookup(result => result.Category,
                                         result => new { result.Priority, result.Count });


            foreach (var result in query)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", result.Key);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" : ", result.Key);
                foreach (var subresult in result)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", subresult.Priority, subresult.Count);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", subresult.Priority, subresult.Count);
                }
            }
```

Please note that some categories don't have values for each of the bug types.

I know how to do this in XAML. I want to do this in "code behind". Any pointers on this would be appreciated. The code I sued to create the graph is plain XAML:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" ImageLocation="~/FolderLocation/Chart_#SEQ(1000,0)" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ImageType="Png" IsSoftShadows="true">

      <series>
        <asp:Series Name="Championships" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="StackedColumn" > 
         <Points> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Audio" YValues="17" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Video" YValues="15" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Peripheral" YValues="6" />            
         </Points> 
        </asp:Series> 
        <asp:Series Name="Championships2" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="StackedColumn" > 
         <Points> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Audio" YValues="2" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Video" YValues="5" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Peripheral" YValues="16" /> 
         </Points> 
        </asp:Series> 
        <asp:Series Name="Championships3" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="StackedColumn" > 
         <Points> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Audio" YValues="10" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Video" YValues="3" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Peripheral" YValues="16" /> 

         </Points> 
        </asp:Series> 
        <asp:Series Name="Championships4" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="StackedColumn" > 
         <Points> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Audio" YValues="10" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Video" YValues="3" /> 
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Peripheral" YValues="16" /> 
         </Points> 
        </asp:Series> 
      </series>
            <chartareas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                    <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </chartareas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

I would also like to display the number of bugs on each stack component.

How do I create this stacked chart by writing code and not in XAML?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) witch are pure javascript and they are more interactive instead of Microsoft charts. Also it's easy to create them in code behind by using [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com) library. Here is code for creating a stacked column chart:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Stacked column chart" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Championships 1", "Championships 2", "Championships 3", "Championships 4" } })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions { Column = new PlotOptionsColumn { Stacking = Stackings.Normal } })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series { Name = "Audio", Data = new Data(new object[] { 17, 2, 10, 10 }) },
                           new Series { Name = "Video", Data = new Data(new object[] { 15, 5, 3, 3 }) },
                           new Series { Name = "Peripheral", Data = new Data(new object[] { 6, 16, 16, 16 }) }
                       });
```

And here is the result from the code:
[image: This is the stacked column chart]

Also you can see live demo of Highcharts [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked).

More about how to install and use the DotNet.Highcharts library you can find on [home page at CodePlex](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com). More sample code you can find in the [example project](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/83064).